# Unable to click the Search(magnifying glass) button in Android keyboard using Appium/Selenium/Java

Tags: android, selenium, selenium-webdriver, appium

I am unable to select the Search button on the *Android* keyboard the one with Magnifying Glass using *Appium/Selenium* and `Java`. I have gone through earlier threads on stackoverflow and none of the threads were helpful.

Need expert help! Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can use this to use search button on the keyboard:

```
driver.sendKeyEvent(AndroidKeyCode.ENTER);
```

Comment: try keycode for search button- Constant Value: 84 (0x00000054)

Answer (score 0):

adb -s UDID_VALUE shell input keyevent 84
or
adb -s UDID_VALUE shell input keyevent KEYCODE_SEARCH